# reference multiple python classes in one build.load_string

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have python file that is supposed to **reference multiple classes** firstscreenScreen and secondscreenScreen in the **Builder.load_string**.
However what it does it shows the error unknow class secondscreenScreen. I guess this is because it searches only for the first class and ignores others. I have deleted the irrevelant code here. How can I include two or multiple files in one buildloader is there an option to include 2 buil.load_string and still be able to switch screens?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button



Builder.load_string("""
#:kivy 1.9.0

<firstscreenScreen>:
   Word:

<secondscreenScreen>:
    WordList:
        Label:
            id: label1
            text: self.parent.txt1

""")



class Word(Widget):
    pass


class firstscreenScreen(Screen):

    pass


class secondscreenScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


   sm = ScreenManager()
   sm.add_widget(firstscreenScreen(name='firstscreen'))
   sm.add_widget(secondscreenScreen(name='secondscreen'))


class WordApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (0,0,0.3,1)
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
     WordApp().run()



class WordList(Widget):
    txt1 = "abc"
class firstscreenScreen(Screen):
    pass


class secondscreenScreen(Screen):
     pass

class WordListApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (0,0,0.3,1)
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
 WordListApp().run()
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 `__main__`?

Comment: I forgot to delete second __main__

Comment: edit and improve your indentation, another error I see is that the Word class is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the classes before you've defined them. Move the class definitions to before the load_string command.

Comment: Ok it does make a difference but still doesnt work the way I want it to. I have lots of code in both screens but it just shows a blank blue screen.

Comment: Glad to hear it fixed your first problem. I was very confused when you said it didn't make a difference. It's not clear from your example code exactly what you want it do, so I'd suggest posting a new question with the new problems you're encountering.